# How to crop the UIImage to have rounded corener

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a requirement in which i need to crop the UIImage's top right and bottom right corner with specified radius. The final output shall look like below image's coreners

[image]

Can you any one please help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_backgroundImageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomRight)cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
_backgroundImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

`self` is my Custom table view Cell .

Comment: If i use this can i apply shadow to the backgroundImageView?

Comment: I tried but backgroundImageView shadow does not appear.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403578/how-can-i-add-shadow-to-a-circle-uiimageview

Answer (score -1):

The simple way to do this

```
 ImageView.layer.cornerRadius  = 10.0f;
    ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    ImageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor  whiteColor] CGColor];
```

And cover the left side with equal background color . Then it'll be appear like right top and right bottom is cornered

Comment: It applies to all corner of image.