# How to set bottom shadow of curved view

Tags: ios, swift, dropshadow

I have created a view that is curved from bottom. I have to drop a shadow below the curved path.

```
func addBottomRoundedEdge(desiredCurve: CGFloat?) {
    let offset: CGFloat = self.frame.width / desiredCurve!
    let bounds: CGRect = self.bounds
    let rectBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height / 2)
    let rectPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rectBounds)
    let ovalBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x - offset / 2, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width + offset, height: bounds.size.height)
    let ovalPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ovalBounds)
    rectPath.append(ovalPath)

    let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = bounds
    maskLayer.path = rectPath.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Comment: Add the screenshot. And explain what's not working with your code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XTq4EjHHHNp6Ed9MPA-Dvrag3gzTMJ0F

Comment: here is the screen shot . I just want shadow like this. my code is working for curve path but in unable to get set shadow below it

Comment: have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403762/4056108)